# Button to display next column in Database

Tags: android, sqlite, button

Can anyone please explain to me why the screen doesn't display the next result in my database when I press it? I know the button gets picked up, just can't figure out why it doesn't do anything.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment 
    {

        public PlaceholderFragment() 
        {
        }
        Cursor c;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_resultsand_statistics, container, false);


            Button next = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.next_result);
            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    c.moveToNext();
                }
            });

            SQLController db = new SQLController(getActivity());
            TextView PA = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.PlayerA);
            TextView PB = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.PlayerB);
            TextView PAS = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.PlayerAS);
            TextView PBS = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.PlayerBS);
            db.open();

            c = db.readData();
            c.moveToFirst();
            String s = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("playerA_name"));
            PA.setText(s);
            s = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("playerB_name"));
            PB.setText(s);
            s = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("playerA_score"));
            PAS.setText(s);
            s = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("playerB_score"));
            PBS.setText(s);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you have updated your cursor, but you forget to update the Views! try it like this:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment 
{

    public PlaceholderFragment() 
    {
    }

    public void updateViews(Cursor c){
        String s = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("playerA_name"));
        PA.setText(s);
        s = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("playerB_name"));
        PB.setText(s);
        s = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("playerA_score"));
        PAS.setText(s);
        s = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("playerB_score"));
        PBS.setText(s);
        return rootView;

    }


    SQLController db;
    TextView PA;
    TextView PB ;
    TextView PAS;
    TextView PBS;

    Cursor c;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_resultsand_statistics, container, false);


        Button next = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.next_result);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                c.moveToNext();
                updateViews(c);
            }
        });

        db = new SQLController(getActivity());
        PA = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.PlayerA);
        PB = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.PlayerB);
        PAS = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.PlayerAS);
        PBS = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.PlayerBS);
        db.open();

        c = db.readData();
        c.moveToFirst();
        updateViews(c)


    }
}
```